Recovering an stored handler in Windows Registry
I want to save and retrieve the handler of my current Ribbon in the Windows registry but everything in the registry is saved as REG_SZ (String) not as a handler.
This is mi code:
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public grxIRibbonUI_Repart As IRibbonUI

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As Any, ByRef Source As Any, ByVal length As Long)
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As LongPtr) As Object
#Else
    Private Function GetRibbon(ByVal lRibbonPointer As Long) As Object
#End If
        Dim objRibbon As Object
        'be careful! running this line can restart your Excel when GetRegistrySetting is runing
        CopyMemory objRibbon, lRibbonPointer, LenB(lRibbonPointer)
        Set GetRibbon = objRibbon
        Set objRibbon = Nothing
End Function

Public Sub rxIRibbonUI_OnRibbonLoad(ByRef ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    'Ribbon interface:
    '<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="rxIRibbonUI_OnRibbonLoad">
    '
    '</customUI>
    
    Set grxIRibbonUI_Repart = ribbon
        
    'SaveRegistrySetting and GetRegistrySetting functions from:
    'https://www.devhut.net/vba-storing-information-in-the-registry/

    'Store grxIRibbonUI_Repart handler in Windows register
    Dim Success As Boolean
    Success = SaveRegistrySetting("Installation", "Ribbon ID", ObjPtr(ribbon))
    
    'Retrieve grxIRibbonUI_Repart handler when an error occurs
    If grxIRibbonUI_Repart Is Nothing Then
        Dim Ribbon_ID As String
        Ribbon_ID = GetRegistrySetting( "Installation", "Ribbon ID")
        'Can I use any string-to-handler conversion function?
        Set grxIRibbonUI_Repart = string-to-handler(Ribbon_ID)
    End If
    
    grxIRibbonUI_Repart.Invalidate
 
End Sub

How do I retrieve the handler from that REG_SZ String?
This code works perfectly if I save the handler in a cell on a sheet:
Sheet1.Range("B3").Value = ObjPtr(ribbon)
and I retrieve it from this cell:
Set grxIRibbonUI_Repart = GetRibbon(Sheet1.Range("B3").Value)

You just need CLng  or CLngPtr

CLngPtr(Ribbon_ID) or Clng(Ribbon_ID) instead of 'string-to-handler(Ribbon_ID)' returns a compile error: type mismatch

You should be passing the value from the registry, not Ribbon_ID which is an object.

Thank you Rory for your help. I was trying to assign the string Ribbon_ID (it doesn't matter if I convert it to Long or LonPtr) to the grxIRibbonUI_Repart object. But I should be assign an Ribbon object. The correct code line is not Set grxIRibbonUI_Repart = string-to-handler(Ribbon_ID) it shoulb be Set grxIRibbonUI_Repart = GetRibbon(Ribbon_ID). The GetRibbon API allows a string as argument, even though lRibbonPointer is defined as LongPtr
